# What is the right way to set up a new remote repo in Git? (Original remote repo is lost)

Tags: git, version-control, git-remote

The remote repo I was using is gone now. My local repo has all my history and everything I need. I set up a new remote repo by creating the users, the ssh access, a group called developers, and the directories. Then I created symlinks to the repos in the home directories of each user. Then I initiated the remote repos as follows:

```
git init --bare --shared=group
chgrp -R developers .
```

On my local machine I edited ~/.ssh/config and defined the new host along with the identity file required for that host. Then I edited .git/config and changed remote URL as required. `git remote -v` reports the expected new origin.

Now my question is, which of the following two options (assuming one is correct) do I need to do next? I have seen both of these recommended and I don't know which is appropriate for my situation.

Choice 1:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Choice 2 (but I believe I would skip the first two steps):

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:aplikacjainfo/proj1.git
$ git config master.remote origin
$ git config master.merge refs/heads/master
$ git push
```

I do not understand the command `git config master.merge refs/heads/master`.

My goal is to first get all my local history onto the new remote repo. Then I want to be able to make my commits locally and do a `git push` and have the new remote repo work as expected. Thanks

Comment: How does github have anything to do with this? You said you setup your own server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you already hand-edited `.git/config`, just use `git push -u origin master`. It'll do all that there's left to do.

Comment: After I run this command, is there a way to verify that the remote repository contains all the history and all the files/objects? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to verify, Git is very safe by design. Unless your server's hard drive is failing, the objects are there after the `push` command succeeds.

You can list all the refs on the remote by using [ls-remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) if it makes you feel better ;-)